# Robot framework- Pabot Using Jython

Tags: robotframework

As part of the pabot documentation 
https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot

--command [ACTUAL COMMANDS TO START ROBOT EXECUTOR] --end-command
RF script for situations where pybot is not used directly
is given.Have anyone tried to use Pabot with Jybot command

Exmple:
 pabot --command Jython --end-command TestCasesDirectory

It is failing with assertion Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page has the example:

```
pabot --command java -jar robotframework.jar --end-command tests
```

That uses jython (embedded in the robotframework.jar) or you could also do

```
pabot --command jybot --end-command tests
```

You can't directly run your tests with Jython command in any case - so it will not work through pabot either. The actual command to run RF tests with jython is jybot.

Comment: pabot --command java -jar robotframework.jar --end-command tests. This command is working fine. How to include external jar(say selenium2Library) to the above situation. for normal execution of test case i have used java -cp selenium2.jar: robotframework.jar org.robotframework.Robotframework testcase.html.how to execute the sanme with pabot

Comment: I have tried using pabot --command java -Xbootclasspath/a:robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar -jar  robotframework-2.8.1.jar --end-command  testcases.html/

Comment: Add them to java CLASSPATH environment variable. By the way I haven't seen the a:-drive for the last decade or so...